# Can't open PDF on new tab using target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, html

How do I open PDF on a new tab, target="_blank" alone does not work it still open the pdf in the same tab.

Comment: show us some code

Comment: No code needed, that's just a technical question.

Comment: A good question to ask is [is this an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? So, do you want users to _open_ the PDF and view it or to merely _get it_ without navigating away from a page?  If it's the latter, and you've chosen to do that via opening a new tab/window, you should know that there is also the `download` attribute for `a` tags in HTML5 you can use. It tells the browser that whatever you're linking should be downloaded, not opened. Thus a user can get the PDF and stay on the page.

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1 : HTML**

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

You can simply do that with setting **target="_blank"** for an example check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target)

More [Details](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

**Method-2 : Javascript**

```
<a onclick="openInNewTab('Your URL');">Something To Click On</a>

function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know: "_Blank" is not working as a "new tab" on every browser.

To do that, you have to use js like this:

```
<a href="..." onclick="javascript:windows.open('link', [options]);">Lnk</a>
```

(it will work on any browser, "_blank" will not)

EDIT: Of course, here the "link" in window.open will be the path to where your PDF file is stored.

EDIT2 (thanks to vlaz): Yep, it will work on any browser if JS is enabled, if he his not it will not.

Comment: well, technically the `onclick` will not necessarily work either, depending on whether the browser has JS enabled or not. And `_blank` will work regardless.

Comment: Nope, _blank will not work on all browsers, js will, but as you said "JS should be enabled".

Answer (score 1):

Without your code is hard to tell what's wrong but did a fast test and this worked for me..

```
<a target="_BLANK" href="pdf/your_pdf.pdf">YOUR PDF</a>
```